# Setting a var in mysql and using in new query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I will like to do somthing like this

```
$tagNo = 12345;
mysql_query("var = SELECT `jobNo` FROM `Jobs` WHERE `tagNo`='".$tagNo."';
INSERT INTO `Locations` (`jobNo`,`tagNo`,`name`) VALUES (var, '".$tagNo."', 'blah')");
```

can this be done?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign variables like that, but you can achieve exactly what you're after using the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Locations` (`jobNo`, `tagNo`, `name`) 
             SELECT `jobNo`, '".$tagNo."', 'blah' FROM `Jobs` WHERE `tagNo`='".$tagNo."'");
```

But, [as has been explained in the comments, don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225021/setting-a-var-in-mysql-and-using-in-new-query/20225130#comment30160682_20225021).

Answer (score 0):

you must fetch your query first and then insert the values you want.
or use insert .. select statment.

you can try this

```
 $tagNo = '12345';
 $var = mysql_query("SELECT `jobNo` FROM `Jobs` WHERE `tagNo`='".$tagNo."' ");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($var) ;

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Locations` (`jobNo`,`tagNo`,`name`) 
                     VALUES ('".$row['jobNo']."' , '".$tagNo."', 'blah')");
```

but this is very bad idea using mysql , instead use PDO or MYSQLI